# How Do I Change the Active DIrectory Auditing Events Maximum?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, ldap

We recently starting testing the ADAudit tool and turned on some new auditing features in AD.

I have an LDAP Modify action in a custom program I've written that updates very large memberships for groups in AD (10,000+).   It looks like it has started failing because of the auditing changes.  This is the event description from the Directory Service Event Log.

> While logging audit events for the following object, the directory service reached the maximum number of audit events that could be cached in memory at any given time. As a result of reaching this limit, the operation was aborted.
>
> Maximum number of audit events that can be cached:
>   17000

Does anyone know how to change the maximum limit for this?  I can find no information about it anywhere.

Comment: Is this is an old group that was created before before switching over to Windows 2003 Forest functional level?

Comment: I'd be curious under which event id & source this event was logged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know you've gotten yourself into a pickle if the only relevant search result to your problem is the Serverfault question you just asked.

Give this a try:

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\NTDS\Parameters\Maximum Audit Queue Size
```

You'll have to create the key as it most likely won't exist. It's completely undocumented (publicly) by Microsoft, and therefore most likely not supportable. The only reason I know that Directory Services checks for the existence of that key is because I ran Procmon and restarted AD DS to see what reg keys it searches for.

I haven't tested it out nor do I have an Active Directory as crazy as yours to test it on, but I doubt you'll get a better answer without contacting Microsoft support.

Most of the [other keys](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786642%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) there seem to be DWORDS, so I would start with that.

lsass.exe searches for it during AD DS startup using the function [RegQueryValueExA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Unfortunately I can't see the parameters passed to the function so I can't tell you exactly what type of registry key it'll need to be.  You'll just have to test.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for finding that!.  That's the registry entry the error said to modify, but it didn't exist.  We'll give it a go on Tuesday when I'm back at the office and let you know if that solves it.

Comment: Wait... the error message *told* you to modify that entry? Agh! That would have been nice to know before firing up Process Monitor... oh well, it was fun. I hope it does the trick!

Comment: Yes...I should have put the whole error in my question, sorry about that.  But it worked!  Thanks!